# Is there any way to Delete or Hide Public Access to an Object after a number of Requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am giving my Android App users, the downloads of some personal files using amazon mobile-hub, Now I want users to access their personal files only 5 times, means if a user download his/her personal file more than 5 times, The File in my S3 Bucket must hide app access or get deleted from Bucket.

Or any idea, which can help me to achieve my Goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible using the in-built capabilities of Amazon S3.

The closest option is to use a **pre-signed URL**, which is a time-limited URL. Once it expires (you choose the duration), the URL no longer works.

See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

If you need the ability to "limit the number of downloads" then you will need to serve the content via your application rather than directly from Amazon S3.

Comment: I think this can be implemented, but i want to clear one thing to all other users, This solution is for only when you want to expire the URL after given timezone not after the number of requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we did it,

> CloudFront / APIGW --> Lambda (Returns Signed URL with atomic
>   incrementing count in DynamoDB) --> DynamoDB (Update Count)

Please use [atomic increment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) to update DynamoDB.

Whether the requests are parallel or sequential, you can avoid downloading the object for more than 5 times.

If the user get hold of signed URL, they can access with the specified timeframe mentioned in the URL, any number of times.

Hope it helps.